# Drupal 8: where to include common scripts

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-theming

I am looking at adding a new javascript library to drupal 8. I want the ability to call this library from other modules / libraries.

The way WordPress does this is by the use of `wp_enqueue_scripts`. Using a common library would make sure that my library is loading just once.

An existing implementation of this in drupal is the way you can add dependencies into your the yml files

```
js:
 dependencies:
  - core/jquery
```

Is there a way I can add my own javascript library as the dependency that can be used throughout my drupal instance (all modules and themes should be able to use this as a dependency)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add any custom code, you need to create and enable your custom module or theme, where you can define your custom javascript file in the `my_module.libraries.yml` file, like this:

```
my_library:
  js:
    dist/js/my_stuff.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

In this case, your custom code is placed in de dist/js folder.
Then you should add your library to Drupal. I usually use the `my_module.info.yml` to define my custom libraries in this way:

```
libraries:
  - my_module/my_library
```

You can also use your custom library as a dependency:

```
my_other_library:
  js:
    dist/js/my_other_stuff.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - my_module/my_library
```

More info about attaching libraries:
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module

More info about *.info.yml file:
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/defining-a-theme-with-an-infoyml-file

Comment: I'm familiar with this practice. Actually looking to add a new dependency that can be called in attached libraries.

Comment: You can add your defined library as a dependency too `- my_module/my_library` this can be a dependency

Comment: That commend answers my question.